# Wordpress Readability

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to add "Readability-Buttons" to my Articles. But the Plugin which exists does not work for me because i can´t change the background color.

So on the Readability Site: readability.com/publishers/tools i can make my own Buttons.

How i can put this automatically in all my Posts ? I think in the functions.php it would be the right destination ..

This ist the Code of the Buttons:

```
<div data-bg-color="#fdfdfa" class="rdbWrapper" data-show-read="1" data-show-send-to-kindle="0" data-show-print="0" data-show-email="0" data-orientation="0" data-version="1"></div><script type="text/javascript">(function() {var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],rdb = document.createElement("script"); rdb.type = "text/javascript"; rdb.async = true; rdb.src = document.location.protocol + "//www.readability.com/embed.js"; s.parentNode.insertBefore(rdb, s); })();</script>
```

thanks ahead.

greetz mike

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is to add the jQ to your footer, and add the button to your page.php or any custom pages you've made above the entry content closing div.

Answer (score 0):

The functions.php will be the wrong place. Have a look at [Wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Template_Files) for a description what belongs in which file.

Where exactly do you want to put the button on your page?

Most important for you could be:

- **index.php** or **single.php** for articles, depending on your theme
- **page.php** for static pages
- **header.php** for the page header
- **footer.php** for the page footer

If you put the code in header or footer, it will be shown on all pages if you do not use any [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) with which you can set on which pages (or type of pages) to show the button.

Comment: Thanks for answering. i want it only in each post. in the top of the post. So i have to put the code into the index.php ?

Comment: This or single.php which I formerly forgot to mention - depending on your theme. If a single.php exists, probably you will have to use this one. Just back up and try out, you can't break a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The correct location is functions.php. You add a filter like so:

```
function add_post_content($content) {
$content .= $buttonCode
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_post_content');
```

Hope this helps,
Jason

**[Update]**

For this I'm assuming the code you provided is the button code if not then just replace with the correct button code.

Open your functions.php in the theme folder and add this at the bottom:

To put it below a post you add:

```
function add_post_content($content) {
    $buttonCode = "<div data-bg-color=\"#fdfdfa\" class=\"rdbWrapper\" data-show-read=\"1\" data-show-send-to-kindle=\"0\" data-show-print=\"0\" data-show-email=\"0"\ data-orientation=\"0\" data-version=\"1\"></div><script type=\"text/javascript\">(function() {var s = document.getElementsByTagName(\"script\")[0],rdb = document.createElement(\"script\"); rdb.type = \"text/javascript\"; rdb.async = true; rdb.src = document.location.protocol + \"//www.readability.com/embed.js\"; s.parentNode.insertBefore(rdb, s); })();</script>";
    $content .= $buttonCode
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_post_content');
```

To put it above a post you add:

```
function add_post_content($content) {
    $buttonCode = "<div data-bg-color=\"#fdfdfa\" class=\"rdbWrapper\" data-show-read=\"1\" data-show-send-to-kindle=\"0\" data-show-print=\"0\" data-show-email=\"0"\ data-orientation=\"0\" data-version=\"1\"></div><script type=\"text/javascript\">(function() {var s = document.getElementsByTagName(\"script\")[0],rdb = document.createElement(\"script\"); rdb.type = \"text/javascript\"; rdb.async = true; rdb.src = document.location.protocol + \"//www.readability.com/embed.js\"; s.parentNode.insertBefore(rdb, s); })();</script>";
    $content = $buttonCode . $content;
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_post_content');
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don´t know exactly what you mean .. Please can you explain ?

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it don´t work. :( I don´t want to exploit you .. ^^